# How to acces Model properties in WPF using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and WPF so this might be a broad or a dumb question, but:

I am using the MVVM pattern and have 1 Viewmodel, several views and a couple of models.
All of the views are just Usercontrols which are put on my mainwindow.xaml.

The view in question is bound to a model wich have several properties, one of which i want to use to dynamically change a picture in the usercontrol.

I am having a very difficult time trying to acces this property and my question is how i do this the "right" MVVM way.

**My mainwindow.xaml:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:Device}">
        <Canvas>
            <View:DeviceUserControl/>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

//---- SNIP----

 <Grid Name="grid1">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" />
 </Grid>
```

**DeviceUserControl.xaml**

```
//--- SNIP ---
Image Name="DeviceImage" Source="{StaticResource IconAdd}"/>
```

**DeviceModel**

```
//--- SNIP ---
public enum Typeenum
{
 FrequenceGenerator,
 Oscilloscope,
 Test1,
 Test2
};
public Typeenum Type { get { return type; } set { type = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Type"); } }
```

I want to change the *DeviceImage* based on the type of the object. I have tried dependencyproperties, but it didnt work as expected (It returned the same type everytime). 
I dont really need the notifyPropertyChanged as i am only interested in changing the image source when the Usercontrol is instantiated.

Comment: First, there is no question in this post. Secound, in MVVM the views are normaly bound to the viewmodels and not to the models. A good approach is to hold one viewmodel per view, so there should be a MainView (maybe your main window) with a MainViewModel. Each UserControl-View should have an UserControl-ViewModel. This kind of structure points you to your solution ...

Comment: I think you're right about dividing my viewmodel into one VM per view.  But i have yet to see an example where the Mainview consists of several views each with their own viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should bind Views to ViewModels, not Models. At least that's what MVVM is all about. Also, if you want something to happen when a property changes, then one way is to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event in your ViewModel (which I assume you know should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) then put your logic on what should happen on the property change there.

**Code Sample**

```
this.PropertyChanged += (s,e)=>{
    // Your code here.
    // e.g. this.MyImageSource = "http://img.com/image.jpg"
}
```

The code sample assumes that your event for the property changes is called `PropertyChanged` and that the image control's source is data bound to the `MyImageSource` property in the ViewModel.
Hope this helps.